# Getting an empty JavaScript Array in Java (Selenium test)

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, selenium-webdriver

I need to get an empty array declared in a JavaScript script in a Java variable.

The JavaScript array is declared as so on a web page:

```
tc_vars["products"] = new Array();
```

(I only need the `products`'s array, not the `tc_vars` one).

This is how I try to get this variable in Java :

```
Object[] value = (Object[]) js.executeScript("return tc_vars['products'];");
```

(Where `js` is a `JavascriptExecutor` associated with a Selenium `WebDriver`).

I usually have no trouble using this method for getting Strings, but it seems it just won't work for an empty Array. Moreover, I don't have any error message, the WebDriver just crashes.

The `executeScript` method returns an `Object` variable. Casting it to a `String` (when the JS variable is a String) works well, but I had no chance in casting this empty Array to `String[]` or `Object[]`.

Comment: Be careful how you title your question: you don't want to get it "in Java" (generic), you want to get it in a Selenium test which is actually a very rare case where it is a valid requirement to want to do this. I'd edit that if I were you, the way you put it now is a big lure for people to not read the question and just defensively vote it down.

Comment: As for the actual question itself: I don't want to jump the gun but this smells like a bug in the driver. I'm assuming there is an issue tracker for it somewhere, did you check if this is perhaps a known bug?

Comment: @Gimby Thank you for your advice, I edited it. Whereas the behavior of the Driver seems buggy, it actually always crashes when an runtime error occurs. I don't know how an empty Javascript Array would be interpreted by Java.

Comment: You can do JSON.stringify in JavaScript side and work on JSON deserialization in Java side.

Comment: @sap1ens Thanks for the tip, it will be useful in the future. About my problem, I can't work on it at the moment, but I will try your idea as soon as I can.

Comment: Trivial, but important: do you have access to tc_vars at this point in the page (e.g., if you open chrome/firefox dev-tools javascript console and print out tc_vars will you get the value you're expecting)?

Comment: @dcoder: Yes I get the values of the `tc_vars["var"]` by typing `tc_vars["var"]` in the Firebug console. 
In particular, `tc_vars["products"]` returns this : `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you need to make sure you actually have access to `tc_vars['products']` at the point which you want to test. E.g., manually open a browser, get to the point in the page where you would ask for that value using selenium, open devtools javascript console and check the value of tc_vars. If it's not available to you, it will not be available to the selenium webdriver.

Second thing is that for arrays, the selenium webdriver (at least the latest version: 2.42.2) returns `ArrayList<Object>` and not `Object[]`. so your cast should be:

```
ArrayList<Object> o = (ArrayList<Object>) js.executeScript("return tc_vars['products'];");
```

Comment: Thanks! It works great.
As I answered to your comment, I can access the `tc_vars` array from a browser's dev-tools console. 
I used your example with an `ArrayList<String>` and I'm able to work with Javascript arrays with Java now.